# Python 正規表現の再帰について

Tags: python, 正規表現

Pythonの正規表現についてです。

```
int abc( int a ){
    if( a > 0 ){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int xyz()
    { return aPtr->type; }
```

上のようなテキストを以下のように置換しようとしています。

```
int abc( int a );
int xyz();
```

そこで次のようなコードを書きました。

```
pattern = r'(\)\s*\{\s*(?:.+(?R))*.*\s*\})'
content = regex.sub( pattern, r');', content )
```

ところが意図したとおりに置換せず、結果は以下のようになります。

```
int abc( int a ){
    if( a > 0 );else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int xyz();
```

(?:...) は ... にマッチしても終了しないということだと理解しているのですが、外側の ){ } にマッチしないのはどうしてでしょうか？

いろいろパターンを変えてやっていますが、基本的なところが理解できていないため、意図したとおりの結果になりません…

Answer (score 4):

結論から先に言いますと，質問者様はほとんど正解に近いところに至っていて，次のパターンを使えば目的の結果を得られると思います．

```
pattern = r'\)*\s*\{\s*(?:.+(?R))*.*\s*\}'
```

変更点は最初の `\)` を「0個以上」に対してマッチするようにしただけです．

`\R` は pattern 全体を指すので，(?:...) の部分の非終了条件は「`)` から始まるバランスのとれた `{}` で囲まれた文字列」です．入力テキスト中 `else{...}` の部分は「`)` から**始まらない**バランスのとれた `{}` で囲まれた文字列」になってしまっているので，ここでマッチが終了して失敗するのだと思います．

Comment: \) の後の * は盲点でした。Cのヘッダからコードを除去しようとしているところで、膨大な数のファイルを見て途方に暮れていました。ありがとうございました。